# How should I handle the Selenium .click() method on Safari?

Tags: java, selenium, safari

So, I'm testing this website and when running my automated tests on Safari, the driver instantiates with no issues, the base URL i've given the code to run is hit, but when I try to click anything, link, button or anything, the browser just stands there looking all confused.

I don't have this issue on Chrome, Firefox or Opera, just on Safari.

When the code reaches a .click() method it just stops and doesn't do anything anymore.

Can someone help me with this?

How can I handle this Safari issue with the clicking on elements?

```
@Test
public void NEmptyEmail()
    {
        RegisterPage register = new RegisterPage(driver);

        register.registerPageLink().click();

        register.email().sendKeys("");
        register.submit().click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/main/div/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/label[2]")).isDisplayed();
    }
```

Stack trace below:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'Andreis-iMac.local', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.3', java.version: '11.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: Safari, browserVersion: 12.0.3, javascriptEnabled: true, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, setWindowRect: true}
Session ID: 46FF6974-517C-448F-AD58-16F01177B898
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id="root"]/main/div/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/input}

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at pageObjects.RegisterPage.email(RegisterPage.java:38)
    at RegisterPageTests.NEmptyEmail(RegisterPageTests.java:48)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _browser just stands there looking all confused_?

Comment: It reaches the URL, and does nothing, no clicks on the given element on which it has to click. Then it just closes and fails the test although it shouldn't do that.
On Chrome, Opera or Firefox i don't have this issue. The Tests are run nicely and pass where they should pass and fail where they should fail.

Comment: can you share the URL or would you prefer not to?

Comment: if it were not related to the company I work for, then I would've been happy to share. Sorry :(
But, believe me when i say, the website i'm working on is not the problem. There are no special stuff implemented like iFrames or whatnot

Answer (score 1):

By the stacktrace there is no problem with the click.

```
at pageObjects.RegisterPage.email(RegisterPage.java:38)
```

says that

```
register.email().sendKeys("");
```

is causing `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException`.

After the login page is loaded, is cursor in the 'email' input field (try manualy load the page in different browsers)? If no, this sould work:

```
@Test
public void NEmptyEmail()
    {
        RegisterPage register = new RegisterPage(driver);

        register.registerPageLink().click();

        // click to the input field before sending keys
        register.email().click();

        register.email().sendKeys("");
        register.submit().click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"root\"]/main/div/section[1]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/label[2]")).isDisplayed();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, if not for you, I wouldn't have found the right way to check my login form. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, due to the answer above which helped me see the issue regarding Safari explained in the question, I've found out that Safari doesn't understand when you try to .sendkeys("") with an empty String, thus failing the test;

When I try to .sendkeys("test") with some text, the browser recognizes the input then goes along with the code.

Anyway, in my case and in my context from above, I've found out that it's kinda redundant for me to send an empty string, cause I was working on the validations of a Login Form.

The idea was that I needn't send an empty string, I only had to click the Login button with the input field just being empty.

Comment: Yeah. I experienced more similar issues when I started with selenium, java, scripting... Anyway even small progress is a progress and we keep going and seeking next challenges.